# how to properly use implode() with associative arrays

Tags: php, implode

i have a question regarding the [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) in `php`, i have this `array()`

```
$user_data = array(
    'user_id_num' => $_POST['userid'],
    'fullname' => $_POST['userfname'],
    'username' => $_POST['useruname'],
    'password' => $password_hash
);
```

what i want to achieve is like this for example,

for the fields

```
`user_id_num`,`fullname`,`username`,`password`
```

and for the values

```
'2159','Sample Name','example','mypassword' <- hash password
```

what i have tried so far is this

```
$user_fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $user_data) . '`';
$user_data   = '\'' . implode('\', \', $user_data) . '\'';
```

but i can't get what i want to achieve can someone help me with this? thanks in advance

Comment: You can use plain old `implode($user_data)` for your values and a `implode(array_keys($user_data))` for your keys.

Comment: what do you mean by that? do i still be able to achieve what i want if i will use just `implode($user_data)` ?

Comment: I don't know if  you're trying to do SQL with that but please DON'T! Use some orm if that's what you were doing.

Comment: @Pengun try it out. var_dump the results of both variants and you will see what and how they do. Or just copy&paste one of the other solutions. I would HIGHLY suggest playing with var_dump and understanding what you do there though.

Comment: @ToBe thanks i will take note of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
$user_fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($user_data)) . '`';
$user_data   = "'" . implode("', '", array_values($user_data)) . "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not quote-implode strings like this; while it may work, it's hard to read and prone to errors. The correct thing would be to quote each individual entry properly and implode the result merely with commas:

```
$fields = join(',', array_map(function ($field) { return "`$field`"; }, array_keys($user_data)));
$data   = join(',', array_map(function ($value) { return mysql_real_escape_string($value); }, $user_data));
```

The field names are controlled by you, as such quoting them with a backslash is sufficient. For the user supplied data you need to run it through a proper SQL escaping function **or better yet use prepared statements.** The above demonstrates the legacy method of using the mysql_ extension, something you really shouldn't be doing anymore these days.

The code should more look like this:

```
$fields = join(',', array_map(function ($field) { return "`$field`"; }, array_keys($user_data)));
$placeholders = join(',', array_map(function ($field) { return ":$field"; }, array_keys($user_data)));

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO foo ($fields) VALUES ($placeholders)");
$stmt->execute($user_data);
```

Comment: thanks but i find your code more complicated for me and i want to learn how to properly use this `implode()` method